# Correct way to normalize two audios before using filter_complex amix

Tags: ffmpeg, audio

I am trying to use ffmpeg to merge two audios, in.mp3 and out.mp3, like this:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -i out.mp3 -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest -c:a libmp3lame res.mp3
```

But the final output res.mp3 has different volume levels.

When I run ffmpeg 'volumedetect' it gives these outputs:

**1. For in.mp3**

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -af "volumedetect" -vn -sn -dn -f null NUL
```

Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s

size=N/A time=00:02:07.17 bitrate=N/A speed= 344x

[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 00554a00] mean_volume: -22.3 dB

[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 00554a00] max_volume: -0.3 dB

---

**2. For out.mp3**

```
ffmpeg -i out.mp3 -af "volumedetect" -vn -sn -dn -f null NUL
```

Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s

size=N/A time=00:02:07.17 bitrate=N/A speed= 434x

[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 00441100] mean_volume: -22.5 dB

[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 00441100] max_volume: -3.5 dB

---

Given the differences in Hz, speed, mean/max volumes - what is the right way to normalize the two audios before merging them with amix?

*THANKS!*

Comment: I used this and it worked:                                                                                                    
**ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -i out.mp3 -filter_complex "[1:a]asplit=2[sc][mix];[0:a][sc]sidechaincompress[compr];[compr][mix]amerge" -c:a libmp3lame res.mp3**

Answer (score 1):

One way to make the volume levels consistent is:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -i out.mp3 -filter_complex "[1:a]asplit=2[sc][mix];[0:a][sc]sidechaincompress[compr];[compr][mix]amerge" -c:a libmp3lame res.mp3
```

But this may not be the best way. Please let me know if there are better ways, and what are the pros and cons of the above method. thanks.